# For the asp.net radiobuttonlist: getting a list item by FindByValue and setting the Selected attribute not working?

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist, selectedindexchanged, selectedindex

Probably a basic question but I have the following code:

```
ListItem l = radiolist.Items.FindByValue(mediaTypeID.ToString());
if (l != null)
  l.Selected = true;
else
  radiolist.SelectedIndex = 0;

handleMediaTypeChanged();
```

In the above code, I can successfully retrieve the correct item from the radiobuttonlist, however setting the item to be Selected is not working.  The SelectedIndexChanged event does not fire, and when I call it manually using `handleMediaTypeChanged()` the radiobuttonlist does not reflect a changed index.  What is the proper way if this isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the SelectedIndexChanged event will only fire when you've physically changed the index from the UI.

You can try something like this:

```
ListItem l = radiolist.Items.FindByValue(mediaTypeID.ToString());

radioList.ClearSelection();
if (l != null)
    l.Selected = true;
```

Comment: Interesting... this solved the problem with the radiobuttonlist not updating correctly.  I don't really understand why, but it seems like something to do with timing, almost as if the code-behind makes changes, but then the viewstate kicks in and resets the list to be what the selected value was previously.  I was getting some weird behaviours for a bit.  But adding that method solves it, so thanks.

Comment: oh, one thing tho, the event handler still does not fire, so I still have to call it manually.  Is that not normal?

Comment: @Gregory Johnson: I think the SelectedIndexChanged event only fires when you manually change the index from the UI/page.